# SQL Query to join 3 tables, resulting a ordered and sorted list

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I write a Query to join 3 tables, resulting a ordered and sorted list?

I have 3 tables with the following structure :

Table Users:

```
|---------------------------|
|           Users           |
|---------------------------|
|      ID     |     Name    |
|-------------|-------------|
|      1      |     John    |
|-------------|-------------|
|      2      |     David   |
|-------------|-------------|
|      3      |     James   |
|-------------|-------------|
|      4      |     Jack    |
|-------------|-------------|
```

Table Questions:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|                    Questions                          |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|   ID  |     Question                                  |
|-------|-----------------------------------------------|
|   1   |     How old are you working in this company?  |
|-------|-----------------------------------------------|
|   2   |     How many customers do you notice?         |
|-------|-----------------------------------------------|
|   3   |     What is your salary?                      |
|-------|-----------------------------------------------|
|   4   |     Do you speak another language?            |
|-------|-----------------------------------------------|
```

Table Replies

```
|----------------------------------------|
|                  Replies               |
|----------------------------------------|
|  ID | USER ID | QUESTION ID |   Reply  |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  1  |    1    |      1      |    10    |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  2  |    1    |      2      |    30    |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  3  |    1    |      3      |    3000  |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  4  |    1    |      4      |    yes   |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  5  |    2    |      1      |    7     |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  6  |    2    |      2      |    25    |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  7  |    2    |      3      |    1500  |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  8  |    2    |      4      |    no    |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  9  |    3    |      1      |    5     |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  10 |    3    |      2      |    50    |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  11 |    3    |      3      |    2000  |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  12 |    3    |      4      |    yes   |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  13 |    4    |      1      |    7     |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  14 |    4    |      2      |    40    |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  15 |    4    |      3      |    2000  |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
|  16 |    4    |      4      |    yes   |
|-----|---------|-------------|----------|
```

I need to write a SQL Query to filter and sort these results.
Almost like an Excel.

Example: 
I need to select who speaks another language, who serves from 5 to 100 clients, ordering for the decreasing salary and years in the descending company.

It should result like this:

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                            Result                                  |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
| ORDER |  NAME  | QUESTION 1 | QUESTION 2 | QUESTION 3 | QUESTION 4 |
|-------|--------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|   1   |  John  |     10     |     30     |    3000    |     Yes    |
|-------|--------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|   2   |  Jack  |     7      |     40     |    2000    |     Yes    |
|-------|--------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|   3   |  James |     5      |     50     |    2000    |     Yes    |
|-------|--------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  Stack Overflow tries to not be a free code writing/homework service.

Comment: Yes.
I'm trying something like this:

SELECT
 users.name, users.id
 FROM users
 WHERE
 users.id IN ( 
 SELECT replies.id_user
 FROM replies
 WHERE id_question = 4 AND reply = "Yes"
 UNION
 SELECT replies.id_user
 FROM replies
 WHERE id_question = 2 AND reply > 5 AND reply < 100

Comment: Sorry, but it's my first time making a question here. rs

Comment: What's the expected result if suddenly a 5th question is added?

Comment: The reply for the new question will be listed on the result and can be filtered too if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the `JOIN` with *conditional* aggregation :

```
select u.user_id, u.name,
       max(case when r.QUESTIONID = 1 then r.reply) as QUESTION1,
       max(case when r.QUESTIONID = 2 then r.reply) as QUESTION2,
       max(case when r.QUESTIONID = 3 then r.reply) as QUESTION3,
       max(case when r.QUESTIONID = 4 then r.reply) as QUESTION4
from Replies r inner join 
     Users u
     on u.user_id = r.user_id
group by u.user_id, u.name;
```

**EDIT :**

```
select t.*
from ( <query> ) t
where . . .;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.
I'm trying to filter and order using the results from replies, but it isn't working.
I'm doing something wrong?

Example:
WHERE QUESTION1 > 5 AND QUESTION1 < 100

OR:
ORDER BY QUESTION2

Comment: @ViniciusTesoni. . . Use `subquery`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It Worked!